# How to write a semantic action for populating a map with a known key?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to dynamically build a parser from other parameters using `boost::spirit:qi`. The goal is to parse a string and populate a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` with keys and values. However, the key field of the map is not parsed (i.e. it is known before the parser is generated).

I'm guessing I need to write a semantic action that sets the map's key to the appropriate parsed value. I can see that `qi::_1` provides the content of the parser, but how do I refer to the return structure (in this case a `std::map`)?

If the `std::map` were in-scope, I could directly assign it like this:

```
parser = lit(prefix) >> value_parser[map_[key] = _1];
```

But in my case, I want to actually generate a parser, not do the parsing. I'm guessing I need something to replace `map_[key]`.

---

To provide a little more context (as requested):

I first parse a "template" string that looks something like this:

```
/path/to/:somewhere:/nifty.json
```

The `:somewhere:` is meant to represent any string that can later be referenced by the name `somewhere`. I have that parser working well.

Next I want to generate from that template another parser that parses strings like this:

```
/path/to/anywhere/nifty.json
```

And provide me a `std::map<std::string, std::string> m` where `m["somewhere"] == "anywhere"`.

Comment: Can you share a little more detail on this? I'd like to help but I can't figure out how the key is known in advance.  Is there a list of keys somewhere?  Or only a single one?  Also, why isn't the map in scope?  It can be a (reference) data member of your grammar, initialized when the grammar itself is.

Comment: Sure: I actually need two grammars. The first one parses a "template" of sorts to provide me with a vector of keys. I then need to take this series of keys and dynamically create a parser that accepts a certain format and stores the fields with the keys already provided. It *is* possible that I could generate the parser AND do the parsing in one step, but the program will be using the generated parser countless times and I want to cache it.

Comment: And I added some context.

Comment: Is the approach described in the first answer sufficient?  You can define a rule (which is a parser) that takes as parameters (a.k.a inherited attributes) your map and the key you wish to assign, and performs the store as its semantic action.  See "maprule".

Comment: I think that would work, but it's not exactly what I was hoping for. I want to generate a stand-alone parser (i.e. no provided `&map`s). I think I may have a solution based on `qi:attr` but I'm not quite there yet.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind but inherited attributes might be the answer for you.  Instead of dynamically creating a parser, you create a single parser taking the key and a reference to your map as inherited attributes that you supply on each invocation:

```
// an attempt to demonstrate a parser that takes a std::map by reference and a key by value,
// then stores a parsed value into the map as the value associated with the given key

#include <string>
#include <map>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

typedef std::string::const_iterator fwd_iter_t;

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

typedef int value_t;  // or whatever
typedef std::map<std::string, value_t> result_map_t;
// key insight - rules can take "inherited" attributes (parameters in 2nd argument):
typedef qi::rule<fwd_iter_t,
                 void(result_map_t&, std::string),       // inherit map ref and key to use
                 boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> map_insert_rule_t;

int main() {

   result_map_t result_map;
   std::vector<std::string> keys = { "A", "B", "C" };
   std::string test_data = "PREFIX 1\nPREFIX 2\nPREFIX 3";

   using boost::phoenix::construct;   // to create pairs
   using boost::phoenix::insert;      // to add pairs to the map
   typedef result_map_t::value_type result_map_pair_t;
   // use Phoenix actions to construct the key/value pair and insert it
   map_insert_rule_t maprule = qi::lit("PREFIX")
                            >> qi::int_[insert(qi::_r1,   // inherited map ref
                                               construct<result_map_pair_t>(qi::_r2, qi::_1))];

   fwd_iter_t beg = test_data.begin();
   fwd_iter_t end = test_data.end();
   for (auto k_it = keys.begin(); k_it != keys.end(); ++k_it) {
      using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
      if (!qi::phrase_parse(beg, end,
                            maprule(phoenix::ref(result_map), *k_it),
                            space)) {
         std::cerr << "parse failed!" << std::endl;
         return 1;
      }
   }

   std::cout << "parse results:" << std::endl;
   for (auto r_it = result_map.begin(); r_it != result_map.end(); ++r_it) {
      std::cout << r_it->first << " " << r_it->second << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

You can probably eliminate the std::map reference from the invocation by inheriting from qi::rule and making it a private data member.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use phoenix bind to do what you're asking about, but it seems like if we had a bit more context a much cleaner solution might be available.

```
parser = lit(prefix) >> value_parser[phx::ref(map)[key] = qi::_1]
```

Depending on where key comes from, you might need to use phx::ref for it as well.

Comment: Thank you. I added some context.